Function initially returns garbage value
I have a function, stringToCharArray
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

char* stringToCharArray(std::string str){

        const int length = str.length(); 

        char* char_array = new char[length + 1]; 

        strcpy(char_array, str.c_str());
        char* data = char_array;
        delete char_array;

        std::vector<char> vec;
        for(int i = 0; i < length+1; i++)
        {
            vec.push_back(data[i]);
        }

        return &vec[0];
}

int main(){
    while (true){
        std::string data = "hello world";
        char* dat = stringToCharArray(data);
        std::cout << dat[0] << std::endl;
    }
}

Weirdly enough, when I put it in a while loop, the initial outputs were garbage. After an unspecified amount of garbage returns, it suddenly outputs coherent values. My question is, why did the function output any garbage at all?

Undefined behavior. You're returning a pointer to memory owned by an object whose lifetime has ended. The memory has been released. You must not use that pointer.

You can't return pointers to non-existent objects. Well you can, the above code proves it, but you'll get poor results if you do.

as well as the above problem, you delete char_array; and then immediately access that deleted memory

You almost had the function correct.  The line delete char_array; should be return char_array; and the rest of the function can be removed.

If you ever do new X[y], you are most likely doing something wrong. std::vector or perhaps one of the string classes are preferred.

delete char_array; should also be delete [] char_array;. Very little of this function makes sense.

return &vec[0] returns the address to a char that will be freed when vec goes out of scope - which happens immediately. I second @paddy's assessment. Very little in the function makes sense. What is the actual purpose of this function?

Why don't you use std::string::data() instead ? This function, apart from invoking undefined behaviour at almost every line, does not bring anything more than std::string::data() already does.

Dupe: Pointers in c++ after delete

This question is a bit of an XY problem. OP says "... to fix a problem I've bumped into [...] That problem is now solved". This is a case where the original problem should be described, because this attempt to solve it doesn't actually solve anything.

Pardon me, it seems my question was unclear. In the original problem, there was a function which took a void pointer. Mistakenly, I gave it a char. After prefixing an "&" to the char, everything resolved itself but not before I constructed this monstrous function. Otherwise, this post has served its purpose.

delete char_array; This deletes the memory where you have the data stored and data now points into the middle of nowhere. From there on you access invalid memory and it's all undefined behavior.
Specifically, char* data = char_array; is a "soft copy", it does not work like std::string where copy constructors would be called between the lines. This is raw pointers you are dealing with here - you only copy the pointer not the data pointed at.
Furthermore new[] needs a corresponding delete[], not delete. Or otherwise you only delete part of the memory - the first byte in this case - and leave the rest behind as a memory leak bug.
